# find common element bw pipeline1 and pipeline2

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document -

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b654eecb5973f0a7945d1fa"), 

"userId" : "5b4098790be60f1c2b4c9b4c", 
"creationTime":ISODate("2018-07-30T12:04:32.951+0000")
"event" : "Add to Cart", 

"attributes" : {
    "Amount" : "1000", 
    "Quantity" : "1", 
    "Category" : "shoes", 
    "Product" : "shoes"
}
}
,
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b654eecb5973f0a7945d1fb"), 

"userId" : "5b4098790be60f1c2b4c9b4c", 
"creationTime":ISODate("2018-08-05T12:04:32.951+0000")
"event" : "Item Viewed", 

"attributes" : {
    "item" : "laptop", 
    "color" : "black", 
    "size" : "small"
} 

}
,
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b654eecb5973f0a7945d1fb"), 

"userId" : "5b58463e0be60f139e67cfb9", 
"creationTime":ISODate("2018-07-25T12:04:32.951+0000")
"event" : "Item Viewed", 

"attributes" : {
    "item" : "laptop", 
    "color" : "black", 
    "size" : "small"
} 

}
```

I want

List of userId who perform both event

Add to Cart where creationTime before ISODate("2018-08-04T12:04:32.951+0000") amount=1000,product is shoes

and

Item Viewed event where creationTime before ISODate("2018-08-04T12:04:32.951+0000") ,item is laptop,color is black.

I am using facet for getting my result.

My query-

```
db.getCollection("3_event").aggregate([
{$facet:{
"pipeline1":[
{$match:{"name":"Add to Cart","creationTime":{$lt:new ISODate("2018- 
 08- 
 04T12:00:00Z")},"attributes.Category":"shoes", 
"attributes.Product":"shoes"}},
{$group:{"_id":"$userId",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gt:1}}},
{$project:{"pipeline1._id":1}}
 ],
"pipeline2":[
{$match:{"name":"Item Viewed","creationTime":{$lt:new ISODate("2018- 
 08-04T12:00:00Z")},"attributes.item":"laptop",
"attributes.color":"black"}},
{$group:{"_id":"$userId",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gt:0}}},
{$project:{"pipeline2._id":1}}
]
}},
{$project:{"result":
 {$concatArrays:["$pipeline1","$pipeline2"]}
}},
{$unwind:"$result"},
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$result"}},
{$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gte:2}}}]);                                                      Output is-
{ 
"_id" : "5b4098790be60f1c2b4c9b4c", 
"count" : 2.0
 }
```

Comment: Use [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) instead of `$concatArrays`

Comment: Basically i want those id which are common in both pipeline array.setUnion give us only unique element .So how to know which id is common in both pipeline array. In mu query i am using group by to find common id.

Comment: If your `ids` are same then your document would also be same then It might should work... Or please post your actual  sample data...

Comment: can you add your facet query to the post ?